# Solution verification for exercise with poles

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

I would like to ask if someone can verify that my solution to the following exercise is correct:
[image]

**My solution:**

As $f$ has a pole at $z_0$ we can write

$$f(z)=\frac{b_0}{z-z_0}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_n(z-z_0)^n$$

which is convergent on some annolus about $z_0$. But $f(z)=\sum a_n z^n$ is convergent on the whole disc, except at $z_0$ which implies that there is an overlap consisting of infinetely many points on which

$$\frac{b_0}{z-z_0}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_n(z-z_0)^n=\sum a_n z^n.$$

Moreover, by definition of a pole, we require $h(z)= (z-z_0)(\frac{b_0}{z-z_0} + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_n(z-z_0)^{n})$ to be holomorphic and non-zero at $z_0$. So, by continuity
$\frac{b_0}{z-z_0}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_n(z-z_0)^n$ is non zero near $z_0$. Therefore,
$$\frac{b_0}{z-z_0}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_n(z-z_0)^n=\sum a_n z^n$$
for infinetely many $z$ near to $z_0$ and both of the sides beeing non zero (also analitic).  Thus, we can use analytic continuation to match coefficients. Futher expanding we have
$$\sum a_n z^n = -\frac{b_0}{z_0}(1+\frac{z}{z_0}+\frac{z^2}{(z_0)^2}+\cdots)+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_n(z-z_0)^n$$

Matching coeficients for $z^{n}$ gives
$$a_n=-\frac{b_0}{(z_0)^{n+1}}+b^n m_{n,1}+b^{n+1} m_{n,2} + \cdots$$
where $m_{i,j}$ are multinomial coeficients. For the RHS series to converge for values of $z\neq z_0$ we require the existance of $A \in N$ such that for all $n>A$ we have $|b_n| < \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon>0$. Thus, when $n$ is large, $a_n \rightarrow \frac{b_0}{(z_0)^{n+1}}$. And so

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty }\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty } \frac{\frac{b_0}{(z_0)^{n+1}}}{\frac{b_0}{(z_0)^{n+2}}}=z_0$$

**My question:** Is this correct? If not, where is my mistake?

If the answer to the question goes in a different direction please mark your answer with a spoiler as I still want to give this a go.

Comment: This excites me! Are you trying to give a formal rigorous proof of Königs theorem? Wikipedia only showed an in informal intuitive one and I would really like to see a full proof...

Comment: König’s theorem (for complex analysis) however applies for functions analytic holomorphic everywhere except for one simple pole in *any* disk of $|x|\lt R$ for some radius $R$. Your proof looks good to me, but I don’t know what I’m doing - is what you wrote extendable to any disk that (includes the origin). (+ why does including the origin matter?) I leave these questions also for any experts viewing your question

Comment: Hi, thank you for the comment. My biggest worry was that I never used the fact that it is a unit disc, and as you have mentioned, I am too curious  to see if one can extend this for any disc of radius $R$. My guess (pure thought not backed up by anything) would be that the series $\sum a_n z^n$ with a single pole may not exist for all R. And in regards to the origin I would think that the existance of such series determines that if the function is not holomorphic on the origin then the origin is a removable singularity impluing that it is actually holomorphic on it. Again, I am not sure about

Comment: this but I would too like to know what is happening here.

Comment: @ everyone reading this - I promise I can speak English; weird things happen when you type on phones and auto correct gets involved, and I can’t edit the mistakes out of the comments now! The theorem I mention is [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6nig%27s_theorem_(complex_analysis)) one

Comment: Revisiting this question, I realise that in most of the places where you write $b_0$, you really mean $b_{-1}$ from the Laurent series